# How to print element selected in 0/1 knapsack problem using Recurssion

Tags: c++, c++14, dynamic-programming

I have a code  for 0/1 Knapsack with Recursion. I want to print **selected element** along with profit. 
Code is giving only profit. 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

int knapSack( int weight, int wt[], int val[], int n)
{
    if( weight <= 0 )
       return 0;

    if( n < 0 )
      return 0;

    // nth element is excluded  
    int exclude = knapSack(weight, wt, val, n-1);

    // nth element is included
    int include = knapSack(weight - wt[n], wt, val, n-1) + val[n];

    return  max( include, exclude);
}

int main()  
{  
    int val[] = {60, 100, 120};  
    int wt[] = {10, 20, 30};  
    int W = 50; 

    int n = sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]);  
    cout<<knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1); 

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995949/how-to-get-the-list-of-selected-items-in-0-1-knapsack) might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a vector to save the collected items

```
int knapSack( int weight, int wt[], int val[], int n, vector<int>& items) 
{
    if( n < 0 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    vector<int> tmp1 = items;
    vector<int> tmp2 = items;
    // nth element is excluded 
    int exclude = knapSack(weight, wt, val, n-1, tmp1);

    // nth element is included
    int include = 0;
    if (weight >= wt[n]) {
        tmp2.push_back(val[n]);
        include = knapSack(weight - wt[n], wt, val, n-1, tmp2) + val[n];
    }

    items = (include >= exclude) ? tmp2 : tmp1;
    return  max( include, exclude);
}

int main()  
{  
    int val[] = {60, 100, 120};  
    int wt[] = {10, 20, 30};  
    int W = 50; 

    vector<int> items;
    int n = sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]);
    int profit = knapSack(W, wt, val, n-1, items);

    cout << "profit: " << profit << endl;
    cout << "items: ";
    for (auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    } 

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: What is the time complexity of this knapsack function?